# Rails routes with scope “:locale” and nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have doubt in routes in rails.

In my new project i have models  name as

```
  1. Country
  2. States
  3. Category
  4. Subcategory
  5. advertisements
```

i want to generate routes like below

```
1. /en
2. /en/advertisements
3. /en/indiana
4. /en/indiana/advertisements
5. /en/indiana/cars
6. /en/indiana/cars/advertisements
7. /en/indiana/cars/bmw/advertisements
8. /en/cars/advertisements
```

ex :-

```
  en is country locale
  indiana is state
  cars is category
  bmw is sub category
```

Here is my routes declaration in routes.rb

```
  scope ":language" do <br />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;scope "(:state)" do <br />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; scope "(:main_category)" do <br />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      scope "(:category)" do <br />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;    resources :advertisements <br />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;    match "search" => "advertisements#index"
       <br />  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;end<br />
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; end<br />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  end<br />
  end  <br />
```

The above routes work correctly if the url is "/en/indiana/cars/bmw/advertisements"

Now i want routes for   "/en/cars/advertisements"
"/en/cars/advertisements" then it will assign en to language and cars to state

How can i declare routes for this "/en/cars/advertisements",

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to model your resources this way?
Cause by your url scheme you are trying to imply that the car resource itself would be different when the language changes. I would rather have the locale as a parameter. Than to say that the locale has an impact on the collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use match routes. I thought this may solve your problem.

```
   match '/:language/:category/advertisements' => 'controller#action_name'
```